# How to bind to Combobox inside of the DataGridTemplateColumn

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox, binding, datagrid

I have created DataGrid that among the other controls contains a combobox. If I am using `DataGridComboBoxColumn` I have no problem with binding the data. But when it is not in the edit mode `DataGridComboBoxColumn` is actually a `TextBlock` which is not a good user experience so I switched to the standard `ComboBox` and wrapped it inside of the `DataGridTemplateColumn`. Unfortunately, I don't know how to bind it properly and I am honestly going in circles. I have tried to find something relevant in the book WPF 4 Unleashed, but it was unsuccessful.

I have implemented the Parse button to output the data, but the parsed data is always the same, even after I change the selected item in the combobox.

I have made an example of the problem:
https://github.com/pytagora/stackoverflow/tree/master/ComboBoxBinding

The idea is to bind the instance of my custom class that has properties Id and Name to the combobox. The name should be shown to the user and when I have to proceed to do something else I wish to have a valid Id of the selected item.

Is it possible to solve this issue by setting the properties of combobox properly or is it required to use the observer pattern?